# Rule ineffective in Atom's styles.less

Tags: css, less, atom-editor

In an attempt to achieve a clearer bracket matching highlight scheme, I came up with the following snippet for *styles.less*:

```
atom-text-editor.editor {
    .bracket-matcher .region {
        border          : none;                     //   effective
        background-color: @syntax-text-color;       //   effective
        color           : @syntax-background-color; // ineffective
    }
}
```

There are no conflicting rules preceding or succeeding this extract.

What could be a possible reason for this behaviour?

Comment: What does the console show? Also have you added !important to double check nothing is conflicting?

Comment: @mayersdesign Changing it to `color: @syntax-background-color !important;` makes no difference. I'm not sure what to look for in the console - no related errors or warnings. When I place the cursor next to a brace (to trigger the highlight) and filter by `atom-text-editor` in the Styles section of DevTools, I see no relevant results. Could you please try this snippet and see if you face the same issue?